# JavaScript Error occurs only on debugging and on each and every debugging line

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, angular, cesiumjs

We built a cesium based tool. I'm working with Chrome and its Dev Tools.

The application works perfectly except when I debug it. Before each and every line of debugging I'm getting an Error -  (`n.toString() is not a function`). The error won't specify any line number which makes it even harder to find.

I tried to set:
`window.onerror = function(error){console.log(error);}` but it won't get there. (I even generated errors and saw them logged correctly).

The tool is on a standalone station therefore I can't upload any of the code I'm using.

**IMPORTANT:** The errors are thrown for each and every line I'm debugging. (e.g: I put a breakpoint, and I already have 2 lines of exception. Going to the next line using F11 / F10, and there are 2 more lines... and it continues forever)

**UPDATE 1:** Checked different versions of Chrome and I found out that on Chrome v41.xxx the bug won't occur, while in Chrome v51.xxx it does.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: clear your watcher toolbox, perhaps there is an `n` variable trying to be watched while it doesn't exist

Comment: @arhak Thanks for the fast response. Checked the watcher toolbox. It's empty. The tool was tested on a few computers which makes the chance of dirty watcher toolbox even lower.